# sonarqube 4.5.2->5.3 db migration failure

Tags: mysql, sonarqube, upgrade

I am upgrading from Sonarqube 4.5.2 to 5.3 and the db migration failed. I am running on RH-Linux using MySQL. After running for 7 hours I got the following stacktrace. What is the state of the DB? What is my next step?

```
2016.02.29 18:36:16 INFO  web[o.s.d.v.MassUpdate] 114749 issue_changes processed
 (183 items/sec)
2016.02.29 18:37:09 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.DatabaseMigrator] Fail to execute databa
se migration: org.sonar.db.version.v51.FeedIssueChangesLongDates
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error during processing of row: [created_at=201
5-07-01 23:54:59.0,updated_at=2015-07-01 23:54:59.0,issue_change_creation_date=2
015-07-01 23:28:45.0,id=1418038]
        at org.sonar.db.version.SelectImpl.newExceptionWithRowDetails(SelectImpl
.java:89) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.db.version.SelectImpl.scroll(SelectImpl.java:81) ~[sonar-db
-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.db.version.MassUpdate.execute(MassUpdate.java:76) ~[sonar-d
b-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.db.version.v51.FeedIssueChangesLongDates.execute(FeedIssueC
hangesLongDates.java:49) ~[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.db.version.BaseDataChange.execute(BaseDataChange.java:45) ~
[sonar-db-5.3.jar:na]
        at org.sonar.server.db.migrations.DatabaseMigrator.executeMigration(Data
baseMigrator.java:95) ~[sonar-server-5.3.jar:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.
0_72]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.
java:57) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAcces
sorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) ~[na:1.7.0_72]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirectWithExceptionHandling(Ja
vaMethod.java:455) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.javasupport.JavaMethod.invokeDirect(JavaMethod.java:316) [j
ruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.java.invokers.InstanceMethodInvoker.call(InstanceMethodInvo
ker.java:61) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
        at org.jruby.runtime.callsite.CachingCallSite.call(CachingCallSite.java:
168) [jruby-complete-1.7.9.jar:na]
:
:
:
2016.02.29 18:37:09 INFO  web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB migration failed | time=25048064ms
2016.02.29 18:37:09 ERROR web[o.s.s.d.m.PlatformDatabaseMigration] DB Migration or container restart failed. Process ended with an exception
org.jruby.exceptions.RaiseException: (StandardError) An error has occurred, all later migrations canceled:

Fail to execute database migration: org.sonar.db.version.v51
```

.FeedIssueChangesLongDates

Answer (score 0):

You have to restore a backup. I hope you made one before starting the upgrade. Searching for FeedIssueChangesLongDates you can find the [here](http://javadocs.sonarsource.org/5.3/apidocs/src-html/org/sonar/db/version/v51/FeedIssueChangesLongDates.html#line.42) the implementation. Look at the queries and the action executed on the records found. Based on that you can investigate the problematic records and correct/update in SQL directly.